# Iterate cost distance/cost path over multiple points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, iterator, cost-path

I have multiple source points in one shapefile and one destination point in a separate file. I would like to find the least cost path from each source point to the destination point.  My costs are weighted using a DEM (elevation only).  I am using ModelBuilder to iterate over each source point to produce a cost distance and cost backlink raster to feed into the cost path tool.

I've run the iterator and cost distance tool and they function properly, but when I add in the cost path tool, I get multiple errors after the first source point run:

```
ERROR 010236: Error in building VAT.
ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
ERROR 010414: Error in creating a Raster from a geodataset.
Failed to execute (Cost Path).
```

I'm not very Python-savvy and am using ModelBuilder.

[image: shown here]

Comment: It may not be the issue but the green outputs of your iterator and cost distance tool are using inline substitution in their names when they don't need to be. If it were me I would simply call them Sourcepoint, cd_raster, bl_raster.

Answer (score 1):

The destination point was outside of the spatial extent of the origin points.  Once I adjusted that, it all ran fine.

Here's a link to the post that contained the solution I used: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/77736#post315923